# Remove period added in references when note is present

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

In my bibliography, I write a reference without any periods at the end, but when I write a note, a period appears between the body of reference and the note.
How can I edit a copy of `unsrtdin.bst` so that the perido does not appear?

This is my code:

```
@ARTICLE{M1,
author          = {aaa, bbb},
title           = {css},
journal         = {Journal of Science},
year            = {2015}, 
note            = {accept}}
```

and the output in pdf file is:

```
aaa,bbb: css. Journal of Science (2015). - accept
```

The period I mean is the one after the year.

Comment: Crosspost http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/12725/den-punkt-zwischen-dem-note-und-der-literatur-loschen and http://golatex.de/den-punkt-zwischen-dem-note-und-der-literatur-loeschen-t15128.html. Beside this your tag is fautly, this is not a biblatex question.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: i use unsrtdin, but i make a copy from unsrtdin, so that i can change the file. also unsrtdin

Comment: Try to look for `FUNCTION {article}` in `unsrtdin.bst` and comment/edit or remove `note set.period.dash.check`. Maybe it solves your problem...

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you want: You want to remove the period but keep the en-dash, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for `. -` gives us line 212 of `unsrtdin`.
[image: saliUnsrtdinModified]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{M1,
        author          = { aaa,bbb},
        title           = {css},
        journal         = {Journal of Science},
        year            = {2015}, 
        note            = {akzeptiert}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{saliUnsrtdin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did i answer? To be honest, once i want to have a daily rep of 200 as well. :-)

Comment: +1. I'm happy to upvote bibtex-related queries and answers.